# User position MKAnnotationView display order relative to other annotations in iOS 10, 11, 12

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

How can I set default user location to be placed in front of other annotations.

For iOS 10 layer.zPosition is working fine on any Annotation. In iOS 11 Apple changed something and layer.zPosition is not working any more because MKMapView is modifying zPosition automatically. I know I can use custom CALayer with fixed zPosition and tricky setter that is doing nothing in iOS 11 only but how I can control zPosition of default user location annotation aka MKUserLocation

Here is the code that I have. It works in iOS 10 and 11 for custom annotation views but I can't figure out how to control user location annotation view (this default blue dot with circle area with accuracy radius).

```
class FixedZPositionLayer: CALayer {

    override var zPosition: CGFloat {
        get { return super.zPosition }
        set {
            if #available(iOS 11, *) {
                // do nothing on iOS 11 and later
                print("ignoring zPosition set by MapKit")
            } else {
                super.zPosition = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    var fixedZPosition: CGFloat {
        get { return super.zPosition }
        set { super.zPosition = newValue }
    }

}

class MyAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {

    weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return FixedZPositionLayer.self
    }

    var fixedZPosition: CGFloat {
        get {
            return (self.layer as! FixedZPositionLayer).fixedZPosition
        }
        set {
            (self.layer as! FixedZPositionLayer).fixedZPosition = newValue
        }
    }

    ...

    public func markAsSelected() -> Void {
        self.image = UIImage(named: "search_icon_pin_big")
        self.fixedZPosition = 10 // This is placed over secondary annotations but should be placed under user location annotation
    }
    public func markAsSecondary() -> Void {
        self.image = UIImage(named: "search_icon_pin_medium")
        self.fixedZPosition = 5 // This is placed under selected annotations 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The MKMapView has a method to get the users location

```
let userLocation : MKUserLocation = mapView.userLocation
```

MKUserLocation conforms to MKAnnotation, so you can the use the following method to get an MKAnnotationView.

```
let userView = mapView.view(for: mapView.userLocation)
```

Comment: I know how get reference to user location annotation view. I don't know how to control its display order relative to other annotations on map. This questions is all about it. I just want that user location annotation view be always on top.

Comment: Did you try setting the annotationView.displayPriority = MKFeatureDisplayPriority.required

Comment: I tried without success. BTW `.required` is the default value.